# Test with ISearchIndexClient

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-cognitive-search

I want to test my functions. All of them depend from `ISearchIndexClient`. I tried to create a `Mock<ISearchIndexClient>` but I can't use it because the mock is not accepted from `ISearchIndexClient`.

In my function I'm calling

```
DocumentSearchResult<SearchData> result = 
                           await client.Documents.SearchAsync<SearchData>(searchText, sp);
```

Then, I tried to create my custom client as

```
public class CustomSearchIndexClient : ISearchIndexClient { }
```

and

```
public class CustomDocumentsOperations : IDocumentsOperations { }
```

but I can't override `SearchAsync<T>`.

How can I test my functions? Thanks

Comment: provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand the problem. Would help greatly in trying to figure out the cause of the problem and potentially help with a solution.

Comment: `SearchAsync` is an extension method which would be difficult to mock. If you can check the source code and find out what instance members the extension method is calling you can mock that but that is a lot of work for a simple test.

Comment: I would suggest abstracting such tightly coupled dependencies so that your functions are more testable.

Comment: Thank you guys. I thought it was complicated to create a mock for `ISearchIndexClient` and then my solution: I'm creating my `CustomClient` where I have only the functions I need from the search (basically `client.Documents.SearchAsync<SearchData>`) so I can mock it and test my code. What do you think?

Comment: That is the suggested approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SearchAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.documentsoperationsextensions.searchasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_DocumentsOperationsExtensions_SearchAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Search_IDocumentsOperations_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchParameters_Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchRequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) is an extension method which would be difficult to mock. If you can check the source code and find out what instance members the extension method is calling you can mock that but that is a lot of work for a simple test

I would suggest abstracting such tightly coupled dependencies so that your functions are more testable.

Wrap the azure specific code behind an abstraction you control, exposing only the desired functionality, which should allow you more flexibility in mocking external dependencies to properly exercise your functions when testing,